# Deriving the unconditional mean of VAR(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, mean, vector-autoregression

How can I derive the unconditional mean of a VAR(1)?

Comment: P. 14-15 of Lütkepohl "New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis" (2005) could be helpful.

Comment: No it is not. Because a full proof is not given. He only defined the mean vector...

Comment: Please explain what you consider to be missing. To me, it is a perfectly valid proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can - and only in this case is the mean well-defined - exploit stationarity of the VAR 
$$
Y_t=c+AY_{t-1}+u_t
$$
by taking expectations
$$
E(Y_t)=c+AE(Y_{t-1})+E(u_t)
$$
By stationarity, $E(Y_{t})=E(Y_{t-1})$, which we denote by $\mu$. Also, $E(u_t)=0$. So
$$
\mu=c+A\mu
$$
Solving for $\mu$ yields
$$
\mu=(I-A)^{-1}c
$$

Comment: Yeah, but I need to make clearly the assumption of stationarity or prove it beforehand.

Comment: That is correct. How to do so is something we discussed in another thread today :-). Also note that the $MA(\infty)$ representation used for the proof in Lütkepohl requires stationarity (or more precisely, causality), so you will need that either way.

Comment: MA(∞) representation is that the same as the world representation? Of am I mixing up things? confuse here.

Comment: In regular cases, yes.

Comment: How can I use that to get the MSE optimal prediction? and forecast error variances?

Comment: That is a separate question